# Spark Kubernetes - spark-submit --archives switch does not copy zip to the spark-driver pod

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I think this may be a bug in the spark-submit --archives switch when running in cluster mode with kubernetes.  In this example the data.zip is copied to the /tmp folder on the client but not the spark-driver pod.

The spark-driver pod tries to unpack the zip file and can't find it.

simplified example command ran from the client to submit to the EKS cluster:

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit \
  --name spark-pi \
  --master k8s://https://xyz.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=myrepo.local:5000/spark-py:v3.3.1-j14 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=/tmp \
  --archives data.zip \
  --verbose \
  local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12–3.0.1.jar
```

log excerpt from spark-submit:

```
22/11/03 10:57:38 INFO KubernetesUtils: Uploading file: /home/user/gitrepos/k8s-spark/data.zip to dest: /tmp/spark-upload-8a7d669e-3ca2-4a8a-b37a-51686f5d3395/data.zip...
22/11/03 10:57:39 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: State changed, new state: 
         pod name: spark-pi-6cb5ce843dff6023-driver
```

log excerpt from the spark-driver pod:

```
Unpacking an archive file:/tmp/spark-upload-8a7d669e-3ca2-4a8a-b37a-51686f5d3395/data.zip from /tmp/spark-upload-8a7d669e-3ca2-4a8a-b37a-51686f5d3395/data.zip to /opt/spark/work-dir/./data.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spark-upload-8a7d669e-3ca2-4a8a-b37a-51686f5d3395/data.zip
```

Instead the file was copied to the folder list above on the client.  It did not copy it to the spark-driver pod at least in a way that the automatic unpack can find it.

```
$ ls /tmp/spark-upload-8a7d669e-3ca2-4a8a-b37a-51686f5d3395/
data.zip
```

NOTE: I realize that there are alternative approaches, but I am trying to avoid packaging any data files into the docker image or using shared filesystems and just let the spark-submit call handle this.

My expectation is that the spark-driver pod can find and extract a zip file that is specified with the --archives switch call to spark-submit

Have I misused the archives functionality or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

`spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path` must be a path on a distributed/shared file system (HDFS/S3/NAS/etc.). The spark-submit process uploads the files to that path, and the driver and executors will try to download it from there. Looks like you are referencing some local `/tmp` folder.